What can I expect from an unexpected 1x1 meeting with a HR member?
I received a calendar invite today at 1pm from an HR Team Member Relations Consultant. The invite reads:

I am part of the Team Member Relations team (part of HR) and need to speak to you about a matter I am looking into. I hope this time works, but if not, please propose a different time.

This is a 1x1 meeting but I'm nervous. Any advise on what to expect from a meeting like this?

I'm going to edit this into shape but after that i fear it will still need a goal. Please read the [tour] and the [help/dont-ask] and welcome to The Workplace

Ok i took a WILD edit and guess at what you really want Matthew. Please review what I edited and enhance to fit what YOU want and the goal you have in mind... and please read the links i shared so you can improve your posting here in TWP for future situations and questions you may have

I don't understand questions like this. We couldn't possibly have the slightest clue what this meeting is about or what you should expect.

@Job_September_2020 another answer-material right there. I know this Q is on the gray area, but please don't answer in comments

Take a look at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/126928/5418

@Hilmar, That is an excellent answer. I don't know if that answer could be re-posted here...

@Job_September_2020 if an answer applies almost perfectly or perfectly to another Question, chances are both questions are duplicate or very very very similar.... looking at that question Hilmar linked my mod-eyes see a dupe.... basically a meeting with HR, one-on-one, and OP not knowing what to expect or prepare. Thanks Hilmar, I think that the answers here posted and those posted there complement each other and server the goal of helping OP

Whoa doggie - can HR come up with a more inflated title? That is enough to red massive red flags.

Before going in - stop and think - have you done anything you shouldn't have recently?

Failed to follow a process
Said a spicy joke
Accidentally went to a website that was Not Safe for Work on company resources.

Whilst it may not be directed at you, doing a good mental refresh to check if there is anything you might have done to warrant the conversation.
Next up - Listen carefully, be honest with your answers, but do not offer information not asked for.
This is good life advise - if they ask you about a specific issue, it is generally best not to talk about another issue that you were not asked about.
Stick to the facts of the matter - regardless of whether it is about you or it is about someone else, it is best if you keep Neutral, if it is about a fellow co-worker, even one you aren't friendly with and would like to see gone - don't start slagging them off.
Make sure you get yourself a drink (Water, Tea etc.) - taking a sip of water after a tricky question can give your brain a good couple of innocent seconds to allow you to think about your answer.
Do not be afraid of admitting when you do not know something - It is better to say 'I am not sure, I would have to check my Emails to confirm' than to give a half-baked answer.
This answer is shaped around it being a Disciplinary meeting (either you or someone else) - as the wording suggests it is not a redundancy meeting or a pay rise meeting.
Keep calm, use your manners - even if they are accusing you of the most heinous work-related offenses, you will not help your case by Effing and Blinding at them.
Finally - if it is disciplinary against you - if you feel it is veering into Legal territory, you can always ask to stop the meeting as you need an Advocate, Legal representation etc. This is especially true if they are asking you to sign anything.

Check with your good and confidential coworkers to see if anyone gets the same invite.
If yes, then maybe, this is a routine HR meeting. (For example, they want to get inputs from employees about how to improve certain processes, procedures, etc...)
But, if you are the only one who gets the invite, then this does not look like HR plans to give you a salary raise in this private meeting.
It sounds like something a little more sinister. You are the best person to guess what the reason for the meeting is. (Has anyone accused you of violating the company policy in any way ? or is it a performance issue that the boss is not happy about ?).

Perhaps, you can try to get a hint from HR or from this particular HR person who requests this meeting (Team Member Relations Consultant) by calling them directly or email them and ask them very POLITELY. (Don't make it look like you demand an answer from them). Some questions could be the followings:

What is the meeting about ? Is it a personal matter related to you only ? to your job performance ? a complaint from someone ? or disciplinary matter or something else ?
What can you can do to prepare for the meeting ?
What materials should you bring to the meeting ?
How can you best be prepared for this meeting by doing anything at all in their view ?

They may or may not tell you any hint. But, at least, you can ask.

If you have some very good and confidential coworkers whom you can trust, then you can also ask them to see if they have any clue about the meeting, or if they see or hear anything unusual around.

The meeting may not be as bad as you think. If the matter is so bad, HR would have fired you right away today (with security guards escorting you to the door).
Instead, they want to hear your side of the story, and that is the reason they want to have a meeting with you.

You will know before we can make anything resembling a useful guess. Go in prepared to listen, to try to work with them if you don't like what you hear, and with the knowledge that unless you are already doing something for HR such a meeting will almost always bring bad news.
